# XSL only display calculation for first child only

Tags: xml, xslt

In brief, I would like to calculate the test marks for each student node, but the output only correctly shows the first student's marks and copied it to the other students' marks.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="list_student.xsl"?>  

<university>

        <student>
            <name>Irwan</name>
            <id>8888999</id>
            <pass>1111</pass>
            <ic>911006</ic>
            <group>12</group>
            <team>2</team>
            <program>cs233</program>
            <phone>626134</phone>
            <email>aisya@yahoo.com</email>
            <test1>100</test1>
            <test2>100</test2>
            <project>80</project>
            <assignment1>90</assignment1>
            <assignment2>100</assignment2>
            <assignment3>100</assignment3>
            <assignment4>100</assignment4>
            <quiz1>10</quiz1>
            <quiz2>90</quiz2>
            <quiz3>80</quiz3>
            <quiz4>100</quiz4>
        </student>

        <student>
           <name>aida</name>
           <id>2011585383</id>
           <pass>1234</pass>
           <ic>911006115640</ic>
           <group>B</group>
           <team>14</team>
           <program>CS233</program>
           <phone>0189041004</phone>
           <email>syuhadaaida@yahoo.com</email>
           <test1>0</test1>
           <test2>0</test2>
           <project>100</project>
           <assignment1>100</assignment1>
           <assignment2>100</assignment2>
           <assignment3>100</assignment3>
           <assignment4>100</assignment4>
           <quiz1>100</quiz1>
           <quiz2>100</quiz2>
           <quiz3>100</quiz3>
           <quiz4>100</quiz4>
        </student>

    </university>
```

Here is my XSL:

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?><!-- DWXMLSource="student.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="2" bgcolor="yellow">
      <tr>
         <th>NAME</th>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>PASSWORD</th>
         <th>IC</th>
         <th>GROUP</th>
         <th>TEAM</th>
         <th>PROGRAMME</th>
         <th>PHONE NUMBER</th>
         <th>EMAIL</th>
         <th>TEST (%)</th>
         <th>QUIZ (%)</th>
         <th>PROJECT (%)</th>
         <th>ASSIGNMENT (%)</th>
         <th>TOTAL (%)</th>
      </tr>


      <xsl:for-each select="university/student">
         <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="pass"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ic"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="group"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="team"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="program"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="email"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="(//test1 div 10) + (//test2 div 10)"/> <xsl:text>/20</xsl:text> </td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="(//quiz1 div 40) + (//quiz2 div 40) + (//quiz3 div 40) + (//quiz4 div 40)"/> <xsl:text>/10</xsl:text></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="(//project div 5)"/> <xsl:text>/20</xsl:text> </td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="(//assignment1 div 40) + (//assignment2 div 40) + (//assignment3 div 40) + (//assignment4 div 40)"/> <xsl:text>/10</xsl:text></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="((//test1 div 10) + (//test2 div 10)) + ((//quiz1 div 40) + (//quiz2 div 40) + (//quiz3 div 40) + (//quiz4 div 40)) + (//project div 5) + ((//assignment1 div 40) + (//assignment2 div 40) + (//assignment3 div 40) + (//assignment4 div 40))"/> <xsl:text>/60</xsl:text></td>
         </tr>

      </xsl:for-each>

    </table>
    <a href="index.php">Main Menu</a>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can ignore the calculation. The problem is the output for the tests, projects, and such are the same even though the marks for both students are different.

The result for the second student is the same as the first student even after I have changed the marks in the XML. This might be a simple problem to solve and I apologize, for I have very few knowledge of XSL.

Thank you in advance for any help that is offered.

Comment: Shouldn't you get rid of the `//` before `test1` etc?

Answer (score 0):

The `//` before test1 tells the XSL to go back to the root of the XML, try removing them.